# Do I use myServlet.java or myServlet.class

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets

I am trying to develop a web application but I don't understand should I put myServlet.java or the binary version myServlet.class under /WEB-INF ?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should't move anything to target by yourself, it is managed by your build tool(ant,maven). Please read the [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/a-simple-servlet-example-write-deploy-run/), which is about writing your first servlet.